# using shell script insert data into mysql

Tags: mysql, shell

I want to insert data status info into mysql, shell script goes like this:

```
for intrm in `cat ${intrm_set}`; do
        if [ -d ${bazaar_base}/${intrm}/pt=${dt} ]
                then
                size=`ls -lh ${bazaar_base}/${intrm}/pt=${dt} | grep total | awk '{print $2}'`
                count=`wc -l ${bazaar_base}/${intrm}/pt=${dt}/* | grep total | awk '{print $1}'`
                lmt=`ls -l --time-style=long-iso ${bazaar_base}/${intrm} | grep pt=2016-03-22 | awk '{print $6,$7}'`
                #ls -l --time-style=long-iso ${bazaar_base}/${intrm} | grep pt=2016-03-22 | awk '{print $6,$7}'
                echo $dt $intrm $size $count $lmt

        else
                size='null'
                count='null'  
                lmt='null'
                echo $dt $intrm $size $count $lmt
        fi   
        irt_sql='insert into ${tblname}(DATE,INTRM_TBL,SIZE,COUNT,LAST_MODIFIED_TIME) values("${dt}", "${intrm}", "${size}", "${count}", "${lmt}");'
        mysql -h${hostname} -P${port} -u${username} -p${password} ${dbname} -e"${irt_sql}"
done
```

When it's executed, error throws

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{tblname}(DATE,INTRM_TBL,SIZE,COUNT,LAST_MODIFIED_TIME) values("${dt}", "${intrm' at line 1
```

But when I execute the insert script alone in shell, it works well. Where the mistake appears, Any advice would be appreciated!

```
mysql -hhost -Pport    \
-uuser -ppasswd dbname \
-e 'insert into monitor_hive_intrm(DATE,INTRM_TBL,SIZE,COUNT,LAST_MODIFIED_TIME) values("0", "0", "0", "0", "0")'
```

Comment: I rewrite `irt_sql="insert into ${tblname}(DATE,INTRM_TBL,SIZE,COUNT,LAST_MODIFIED_TIME) values('${dt}', '${intrm}', '${size}', '${count}', '${lmt}');"`,It works!

Comment: You can give an answer to you own question and accept it.